# CloudBuild Github PR workflow is queued and its running indefinitely

Tags: google-cloud-build

I have a cloudbuild.yaml file in my code. I have configured it in a manner where for each pull request, a cloud run url is hosted with prefix as PR_NUMBER from Github and the cloudrun url will be like

https://PR_NUMBER---app-abcd123-uc.a.run.app

Once the URL is tested, code will be merged into dev.

Problem: After a pull request, a build trigger is initiated in cloudbuild and it was finished in 7 minutes. But in the Github, it shows that it has been queued and still running for more than 12 hours. Its costing money in github for running. I am trying to cancel it. But I could not see any option in github to cancel it.

Any idea what could be the reason behind this issue of build got queued in github even though its finished inside cloud build google platform.?

Comment: Did your issue get resolved?